# How to move a child div out of the container parent

Tags: jquery, css

i want to move a child div to front of the screen, the issue is when i add a scrollbar to the parent it shows inside the parent in a scroll

i am using this jquery plugin
popbox plugin:
https://gristmill.github.io/jquery-popbox/
popbox example:
https://gristmill.github.io/jquery-popbox/example.html

here is the sample code as well

`

```
.popbox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

}

.collapse {
    position: relative;
}

.open {
    background: #DDD;
    border: solid 1px #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #CCC;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f4f4f4), to(#e8e8e8));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4, #e8e8e8);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4, #e8e8e8);
    padding: 8px;
}

.box {
    display: block;
    display: none;
    background: #FFF;
    border: solid 1px #BBBBBB;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #999;
    position: absolute;
}

.box a.close {
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: arial;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 11px solid transparent;
    border-right: 11px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 11px solid #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1px;
    top: -10px;
    z-index: 1001;
}

.arrow-border {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 11px solid transparent;
    border-right: 11px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 11px solid #BBBBBB;
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

`

here is html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
    <title>PopBox</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://gristmill.github.io/jquery-popbox/stylesheets/popbox.css' type='text/css' media='screen' charset='utf-8'>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8' src='https://gristmill.github.io/jquery-popbox/javascripts/popbox.js'></script>
    
    <style type='text/css' media='screen'>
        body {

            background: #f7f7f7;
            font-family: georgia;
            font-size: 22px;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFF;

        }

        a {
            color: #999;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .container {
            width: 300px;
            position: relative;
            margin: auto;
            overflow-x: auto;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
            height: 66px;

        }

        label {
            display: block;
        }

        form {
            margin: 25px;
            text-align: left
        }

        form input[type=text] {
            padding: 5px;
            width: 90%;
            border: solid 1px #CCC;
        }

        form textarea {
            padding: 5px;
            width: 90%;
            border: solid 1px #CCC;
            height: 100px;
        }

        .box {
            width: 350px;
        }

        footer {
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        form a,
        footer a {
            color: #40738d;
        }

    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.popbox').popbox();
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class='popbox'>
            <a class='open' href='#'>Click Here!</a>

            <div class='collapse'>
                <div class='box'>
                    <div class='arrow'></div>
                    <div class='arrow-border'></div>

                    <form action="http://gristmill.createsend.com/t/j/s/nklki/" method="post" id="subForm">
                        <p><small>Please complete the form to sign up for the <a href="http://gristmill.io" target="_blank">Gristmill.io</a> mailing list!</small></p>
                        <div class="input">
                            <input type="text" name="cm-name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="input">
                            <input type="text" name="cm-nklki-nklki" id="nklki-nklki" placeholder="Email" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="input">
                            <textarea name="cm-f-tlhll" id="Message" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Get In Touch" /> <a href="#" class="close">Cancel</a>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    

    </div>



</body>
```

i want this child popup out infront of that scrolling parent component(div)

Comment: I added the correct address for the css/js popbox assets as listed on the url you provided and didn't change anything else.. just for having a better picture of the scenario

Comment: anyway as long as I could see, you have your form duplicated and you have this style in your `.container` `overflow-x: auto;overflow-y: hidden;white-space: nowrap;` that will collide with the popup content. Those corrections alone will fix your attempt but it's hard to go any further if you don't better focus your question

Comment: i have removed the duplication in the divs, actually issue is different, i just want my popup to be displayed on foreground

Comment: I submitted my answer one moment after your latest comment... feel free to highlight if wrong assumptions were made

Comment: If the plugin doesn't support adding the popup to the body element then you are out of luck. You will have to find another plugin, rewrite the existing one or write it yourself.

Comment: I deleted my answer. Anyway this plugin is very poor. The furthest I got with it was having a mutation observer to fire when the `display` css prop. was changing for the `.box` element of all the popboxes in the page. I could detach/reattach the element to the container and have it positioned relative to a different container but it was way too far for what you should do. I mean I don't understand why having smaller containers with such buttons and scrambling the structure in real time for the sake of having the element pop off the container.

Comment: Consider also that the size of the "popbox" will be based on the real container also. And anyway there are maybe better options that will allow you to have link and content bound to each other in a very strict way so that they can exist in very different parts of the dom.